# linux metamail package - how to build

Tags: linux, email, c, rpmbuild

I searched for **metamail** package for Linux and how to build it under Centos 7.

I'm interested in using **mimencode** utility which is part of the **metamail** package to process my incoming mail (by invoking mimencode via procmail)

Q:
**Can anybody provide working source tarball and build script to build under Centos 7?**

P.S. I have SRPM which builds OK for my old OS, but it produces an error under Centons 7.

```
....
rm -f uue.o
gcc -c  -I../. -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -g -pipe -DLINUX -DSTDC_HEADERS -I.   uue.c
uue.c:36:1: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
 getline (buf, size, fp)
 ^
In file included from uue.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:678:20: note: previous declaration of 'getline' was here
 extern _IO_ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
                    ^
make[1]: *** [uue.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/rpm.d/BUILD/metamail-2.7-19/metamail'
make: *** [basics] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /usr/src/rpm.d/tmp/rpm-tmp.kxUBlg (%build)

RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /usr/src/rpm.d/tmp/rpm-tmp.kxUBlg (%build)
rpmbuild -ba metamail.spec fail with non-zero exitcode.
```

Comment: `metamail` has been dropped from most distributions because it has not been receiving updates for a very long time. You are probably better off installing a replacement like GNU Coreutils which includes a dedicated `base64` command since a long time; quoted-printable encoding and decoding should be a simple one-liner with Perl or Python (or even Awk, but don't reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source rpm from [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/lux/metamail-2.7-30.lux.1.x86_64.rpm.html) appears to build without a problem on CentOS 7:

```
# yum -y install @development rpm-build ncurses-devel
# rpmbuild --rebuild metamail-2.7-30.lux.1.src.rpm
Installing metamail-2.7-30.lux.1.src.rpm
warning: metamail-2.7-30.lux.1.src.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 53e4e7a9: NOKEY
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Y75vCZ
[...]
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/metamail-2.7-30.lux.1.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/metamail-debuginfo-2.7-30.lux.1.x86_64.rpm
Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IBRR21
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd mm2.7
+ rm -rf /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/metamail-2.7-30.lux.1.x86_64
+ exit 0
Executing(--clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.qiPoiU
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf mm2.7
+ exit 0
```

---

Having said that, I'd like to echo @tripleee: both `procmail` and `metamail` are projects that haven't received updates in **decades**.  For example, the sources in the metamail package used above date from **1994**. I would not attempt to use these tools to handle anything remotely important.